# How do I transfer data from one function to another function in Flutter? Specifically this case

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class GraphPage extends StatefulWidget {

  GraphPage({Key key, this.gender, this.subzone, this.age}) : super(key: key);
  final gender, subzone, age;

  @override
  _GraphPageState createState() => _GraphPageState();
}

class _GraphPageState extends State<GraphPage> {

  int valueData;

  readMe() async {

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/Book1.xlsx");
    var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

    for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
      print(table);
      print(excel.tables[table].maxCols);
      print(excel.tables[table].maxRows);
      for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
        if (row[3] == widget.subzone) {
          if (row[1] == widget.age) {
            if (row[0] == widget.gender) {
              print(row[4]);
              valueData = row[4];
              print(valueData);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ...

  _generateData() {
    var barData = [
      new Stats(widget.gender, widget.age, widget.subzone, valueData),
    ];
   
  ...

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seriesData = List<charts.Series<Stats, String>>();
    readMe();
    _generateData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
```

I want to let valueData be equal to the value of row[4] of my excel file for the conditions below.
However once I put it in generateData() it returns a null value.

readMe() is just a function to read the excel file and try to return a value to valueData for some conditions.

While generateData() is a function to generate data and plot a graph afterwards.

Lets say for row[0] == "String" and row[1] = "String" and row[3] = "String"
row[4] = 5020, but when put inside the generateData() func it returns a null instead of 5020

Thank you for advice.

Comment: When do you call `_generateData`?  In the `build` method?

Comment: @Nitrodon nope. It is called outside of build.

Answer (score 0):

When `readMe()` encounters the `await` keyword, control is immediately returned to the `initState` method.  This means that `_generateData` is called before `valueData` is set.

To wait for `readMe` to finish, you have two options.  One is to wrap the entire process in another `async` method:

```
// This method probably needs a better name
Future<void> readAndGenerateData() async {
  await readMe();
  _generateData();
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _seriesData = List<charts.Series<Stats, String>>();
  readAndGenerateData()
}
```

The alternative is to use `Future.then` directly:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _seriesData = List<charts.Series<Stats, String>>();
  readMe().then((_) => _generateData());
}
```

If you use information from `_generateData` in your `build` method, remember to call `setState` to ensure the widget is rebuilt with the generated data.

Comment: when i do this my whole code doesnt work. before it was just that variable valueData that is not carried over to the genrateData function. Now it just returns me a blank without anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `_generateData` after `readMe()` is compelted:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seriesData = List<charts.Series<Stats, String>>();
    readMe().then(()=>_generateData());
  }
```

Comment: when i do this my whole code doesnt work. before it was just that variable valueData that is not carried over to the genrateData function. Now it just returns me a blank without anything